# Do teachers/professors refer to each other by their titles?

Tags: teaching

I just began shadowing a high school classroom as part of a requirement to earn teaching credentials. The teacher I'm shadowing has a PhD and is referred to as "Doctor Smith" (generic name) by his students. I am not his student and it is the first experience I have in a classroom setting where the teacher is my peer; but, it still feels uncomfortable to call him by his first name.

Do I call him "Doctor Smith?"

If he doesn't have a PhD, should I call him "Mr. Smith?"

When is it appropriate to call someone by their first name?

Comment: Welcome to AC.se. I am not sure this has much to down with academia as defined in our [help]. It seems to be about workplace etiquette.

Comment: What country? These things are very culturally specific.

Comment: @BillBArth United States

Comment: @StrongBad If this isn't fit for the forum, can we migrate it?

Comment: I am only one voice. Let's see what others say. I am not sure where it should go, maybe workplace. I got to run, but if you want to migrate it, flag it and say where you want it to go and a mod will handle it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about primary/secondary education, not universities.

Comment: To answer your title question, in the US it's quite unusual for _colleagues_ to call each other by their titles. In your case, you're a newcomer to the workplace and only shadowing, not really working, so it's unclear whether you quite qualify as a colleague for purposes of this advice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A good safe approach is to start out calling him "Dr. Smith".  Most likely he will quickly say "Please call me Fred" and then everything is resolved.

Answer (score 7):

While you can't necessarily know what title a person prefers, in the US it is almost always acceptable to directly ask them what their preference is.

Answer (score 3):

Try and listen for what other staff  call him, both in the presence of students and staff and follow their lead.